# Line break with MaTeX

Tags: matex

I am using MaTeX to put a box on a graph with an outline. The code looks like this:

```
eps = Epilog -> {Inset[Framed[MaTeX["\\text{0.2~mA/ns}"], RoundingRadius -> 4 ], {105 , 32}, Background -> White  ]
```

I want to insert a line break, so that after the "ns", but can't figure out how to do this. I have tried `\\\\` and `\\newline` and `\\linebreak`, but they are ignored. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MaTeX interprets its input in inline math mode, which means that normally no newlines are allowed. Depending on why you want a newline, you can do one of the following:

- For multiline equations, use an appropriate math-mode environment.

  ```
  MaTeX["
    \\begin{aligned}
    a &= b+c \\\\
    c + d &= e
    \\end{aligned}
   "]
  ```

  [image]
- Use Mathematica's facilities to stack lines.

  ```
  Column@MaTeX[{"\\text{one}", "x+y"}]
  ```

  [image]
- If you really want to use LaTeX's facilities for multiline typesetting, it's possible, but it's not pretty. You can create a parbox of a given size, then type LaTeX commands as usual (including `\\`, which of course must appear as `"\\\\"` in a Mathematica string). Here's an example lifted directly from the MaTeX documentation:

  ```
  MaTeX["\\text{\\parbox{6cm}{
   The items are:
   \\begin{itemize}
   \\item First
   \\item Second
   \\end{itemize}
   }}"]
  ```

  [image]